# Répétition de la préposition « de »

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, standard, style-de-rédaction

La différence entre

> à des fins d'intégration, vérification et validation

et

> à des fins d'intégration, de vérification et de validation

est-elle purement stylistique ou existe-t-il une règle régissant la répétition de « de » dans ce genre d'énumération ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le [complément circonstanciel de but](http://etablissements.ac-amiens.fr/0020017h/portail_lettre/fichesPDF/ortho/compl_circ.pdf) le plus correct est :

> à des fins d'intégration, de vérification et de validation

Son sens est celui de la phrase suivante :

> à des fins d'intégration, à des fins de vérification et à des fins de validation

dans laquelle on omet de répéter la [locution prépositionnelle](http://books.google.fr/books?id=v-1rcAcBJ20C&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=locution%20prepositionnel&source=bl&ots=sjHN5ZdPGd&sig=x4jVvGwcZWmWd4LOTJi3OGRl1RE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ePlnUeC7AsXBtQaiwIHYBg&ved=0CHQQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=locution%20prepositionnel&f=false) *à des fins de*. Toutefois, l'usage courant veut que l'on répète la [préposition](http://www.connectigramme.com/preposition.html/odyframe.htm) *de* devant chaque [groupe prépositionnel](http://francite.net/education/grammatika/page14.html). Il en est de même pour *à*. La répétition des autres prépositions est plus discutée.

**Personnellement**, je trouve

> à des fins d'intégration, de vérification et de validation

bien plus élégant que :

> à des fins d'intégration, vérification et validation

Answer (score 4):

La règle concernant les répétitions les prépositions « à » et « de » serait de répéter la préposition pour chaque mot de l'énumération. Cela dit, ce n'est pas le cas pour toutes les prépositions de la langue.

Je conseille la lecture [cet article](http://rouleaum.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/a-de-et-en-celles-quil-faut-repeter/) pour plus d'informations sur la répétition au sein des énumérations en français.

Comment: Je suggère d'inclure dans la réponse un résumé de l'article en question, et ce pour deux raisons. La première est simplement pour améliorer la réponse en ayant toute l'information pertinente à un seul endroit. La deuxième est pour éviter la perte d'information si lien devenait désuet.

Comment: @Kareen J'y avais pensé, mais je trouve qu'aucun passage n'est vraiment plus pertinent ou intéressant qu'un autre ; je ne vois pas quoi citer en particulier. Par contre, s'il y a vraiment une partie qui te semble pertinente, je te laisse éditer le message.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne sais pas si le style est en dehors des règles...

Ici, la répétition donne plus de facilité de lecture, et rend le texte plus compréhensible à l'oral.

Quand vous dites ou écrivez

> à des fins d'intégration, vérification et validation

... pour comprendre que *vérification* est le second item de liste, il faut que vous ayez lu toute la liste pour prendre conscience que la virgule est le séparateur. Mais avec

> à des fins d'intégration, de vérification et de validation

... ça se comprend dès la virgule et de. D'où le fait que la lecture ou l'écoute sont beaucoup plus confortables.

Quelques fois, l'expression séparatrice est lourde :

> à des fins par exemple d'intégration, par exemple de vérification et par exemple de validation

Evidemment, dans ce cas, ça va moins bien. C'est parce que l'expression séparatrice prend pratiquement toute la place, et demande plus d'énergie à écrire que les items eux mêmes. Le rédacteur doit réfléchir sur... son style, mais, surtout, sur son idée de proposer des exemples. Le style n'est en dehors ni du sens, ni des règles, ni... ni... ni, mais il invite à la réflexion sur ce que l'on exprime ou écoute, ou... ou... ou.